# java file reading issue

Tags: java, file-io

In my java application, I have to read one file. The problem what I am facing, after reading the file, the results is coming as non readable format. that means some ascii characters are displayed. That means none of the letters are readable. How can I make it display that?

```
 // Open the file that is the first
        // command line parameter

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\hello.txt");
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Print the content on the console
            System.out.println(strLine);
        }
        // Close the input stream
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of hello.txt and what does the output display?

Comment: Seems like encoding issue. How was `hello.txt` written? Does the same problem occur with other text files?

Comment: Check the file encoding works with your system's encoding. Java should be using your default encoding.

Comment: the output I am not able to show here..that is why i could not attach..I mean it is not able to paste. yaa this seems to be some encoding issue. I have used many backward and forward slashes in the file.

Comment: What is the encoding of `hello.txt`?

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. Unfortunately examples like this get copied again and again so can you can remove it from your example. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got solved. I dont know how. I copied the hello.txt contents to another file and run the java program. I could read all letters. dont know whats the problem in that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have an encoding error. The constructor you are using for an InputStreamReader uses the default character encoding; if your file contains UTF-8 text outside the ASCII range, you will get garbage. Also, you don't need a DataInputStream, since you aren't reading any data objects from the stream. Try this code:

```
FileInputStream fstream = null;
try {
    fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\hello.txt");
    // Decode data using UTF-8
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
    String strLine;
    // Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        System.out.println(strLine);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (fstream != null) {
        try { fstream.close(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // log failure to close file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do suggest using some utils for this. In commons-io for example there are IOUtils.readLines(inputStream, encoding) and IOUtils.closeQuietely(someSource)

Comment: @PetrGladkikh - Yes, utils like commons-io are good. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this way to handle:-

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, encodingformat));
```

.

`encodingformat` - change it according to which type of encoding issue you are encounter.

Examples: **UTF-8**, **UTF-16**, ... soon

Refer this **[Supported Encodings by Java SE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)** for more info.

Comment: how do you know the file is in UTF-8?

Comment: @buruzaemon: yes, since the person is not mentioned what type of encoding issue. Thats reason I mentioned basic format as "UTF-8". Based on his formatting issue, he has to change it accordingly. That's technically he has to handle. Whats wrong in my answer, which awarded as "-1"?

Comment: You do not know. But this source fragment suggest you need to specify it.

Comment: I don't know the reason for the downvote, but perhaps it's because you phrased your answer as if UTF-8 was the only possible encoding to use.

Comment: friends as per yours inputs, i have changed from "UTF-8" to `encodingformat`. Where the person has to change it accordingly.

Comment: @SivaCharan I originally downvoted since your original answer assumed UTF-8, when at this point not even the OP knows the encoding of `hello.txt`. And that is the whole issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you doesn't know the encoding the file is in, use [jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/) to detect the encoding used by the file and then use that encoding to read the file as others have already suggested. This is not 100 % fool proof but works for your scenario.

Also, use of `DataInputStream` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is an ascii value ,so you need to type cast it into char or string before printing it.Hope this helps